# what schema permissions are entailed when a SQL Server 2005 database role owns a schema?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

In SQL Server 2005, a user-defined database role can "own" a schema. You can see this in the properties window of the database role.  What **exactly** does this mean in terms of permissions/privileges against the tables in that schema?  What does owning a schema mean?

Or, to ask another way:  If I want a particular user-defined database role to have select/insert/update/delete privileges against every table in a schema, what is the best/smartest way to accomplish this?

I could go into the permissions of every individual table in the schema and grant the privs to the role, but this seems dumb.  How do I do it for the whole schema?

thanks
aj

Answer (score 2):

"Own" means "has full access" or "can do anything."

If that is what you want, just make the group the schema owner.

Otherwise, grant schema-wide permissions to this group. You can grant `select` permission for the schema, and members of the group will be able to select from all tables in the schema, and so on.

See [GRANT Schema Permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187940%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: OK, when I do this: 

  `grant select,insert,update,delete on schema::<theschemaname> to   <therolename>`
I get:

  Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.
I am logged in as sa.  
???

Comment: @Allen Is <therolename> the current owner of the schema then? Make sure it isn't first. That is, transfer schema ownership to `dbo`, then grant permissions on it to <therolename>.

Comment: Yes, Gserg.  That was it exactly. Thankyou.  I had previously set the owner of <theschemaname> to <therolename>.  I set the owner back to dbo, and was able to successfully `grant select,insert,update,delete on schema::<theschemaname> to <therolename>`.

I had set the schema ownership thinking that that was the right way to open up the privileges on all the tables in that schema to members of that role, but it didn't seem to work.  I guess I'm not entirely clear on the privilege diffs between schema ownership and granting schema-based privileges.
aj

Answer (score 0):

MSDN Documentation: [db_owner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180977%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Making them members of the db_owner group for that a particular database will essentially do what you require - of course they have a few extra permissions - such as drop a database.

You could create a new user group/schema, of course as you pointed out you need to set appropriate permissions: [SQL Server 2005 Permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191291%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm not interested in having the members of the user-defined role being database owners.  Please read the question carefully.